# How to use button_to to activate a method in a controller

Tags: ruby-on-rails, button, methods, error-handling

I have a rails 3 app and I'm trying to use a button to activate a method in a controller. Meaning that in my users_controller.rb I have

```
def follow
  ...
  ...
end
```

And in the view (users/show.html.erb) I want a button to call that method. 
I currently have `<%= button_to("Un-Follow", :controller=>"users", :action=> "follow") %>`, however when i click on the button I get the following error: `No route matches [POST] "/users/5/follow"` any idea why?

I'm not sure how to fix this.

EDIT: I fixed the config/routes.rb and fixed that error. However I am still getting an error on the controller. nil id.

EDIT: I was able to get everything working error free. However now when I click the button, it says no view associated. However, I want to just call that method, I do not want a new view. Would it be best to, instead of in the controller, do it in a helper?

EDIT: Lastly, for some reason, when I click the "follow" button everything works. However when I click the "unfollow" button it doesn't work.

Comment: Show us more code. Also, edit an answer and remove description of error you already fixed.

Comment: Do you want the correct solution or do you just want the error message to go away.  This implementation is off much further than you think.

Comment: @Planetpluto: if you don't mind, I'll take over this question and edit it to fit my answer (which you accepted) :-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't necessarily need a view for a controller action. You may just render arbitrary text.

```
def follow
    ...
    render :text => 'ok', :layout => false
end
```

Or instead of rendering a view, you may redirect to another page.

```
def follow
    ...
    redirect_to :action => :index
end
```

Comment: I think someone needs to show him how to do this correctly rather than fix the error message